# Box-Jenkins methodology in a Bayesian framework

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, autocorrelation, box-jenkins

I would like to know if the well-known **Box-Jenkins** methodology for time series analysis transfer directly in a Bayesian framework.

For instance, does one analyze the **autocorrelation plot** and the **partial autocorrelation** plot before fitting the model?

And what about **testing for stationarity**?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This Bookdown seems like a good place to start: https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/chap-stan.html. The link is for the chapter on using Stan, but it looks like the other chapters can be of relevance as well